# struct sigaction is not defined (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

I try to catch a signal, but `struct sigaction` is not defined in <signal.h>.
Previously, this worked on Ubuntu with gcc compiler.
Some piece of code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  199309L

#include <signal.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

HANDLE hCom;
HANDLE hEvent;

void diediedie(int sig) {
    puts("Bye, brutal world!");
    if (hEvent)
        CloseHandle(hEvent);
    if (hCom)
        CloseHandle(hCom);
    exit(1);
}

int catch_signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) {
    struct sigaction action;        // <- this struct
    action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    return sigaction(sig, &action, NULL);
}
...some code here...
```

I read this topic [How do I use sigaction()? struct sigaction is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718687/how-do-i-use-sigaction-struct-sigaction-is-not-defined) , and defined `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, but it didn't help.
I can't understand what should I do and why the code doesn't work.
Could someone explain please for a newbie?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found that in Windows I should use just `void __cdecl *signal(int sig, int (*func)(int, int));`